# Is it correct to use "Good Time" instead of "Good Morning" or "Good Night" etc?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to use "Good Time" instead of "Good Morning" or "Good Night" etc., or even in a letter, such as:

> Hi and good time,
>   ...

Comment: It is not idiomatic. We would only say "Have a good time!" if someone was leaving for a holiday or an evening out, for example, not as a greeting.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not idiomatic.

"good time" is only used in the context of "having a good time", which means [enjoying yourself](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/have-a-good-time).

> **have a good time**
>   Enjoy oneself, as in I hope you have a good time at the beach. This idiom, also used as an imperative, dates from 16th-century England, where it was popular until the late 1600s and died out. Samuel Pepys, in a diary entry of March 1, 1666, wrote, “I went and had as good a time as heart could wish.” In America it continued to be used, and in the 1800s it reappeared in British speech as well. Also see hard time; show one a good time.

"good time" cannot be used as a greeting the same way that "good evening" (etc.) can.

Answer (score 0):

No, as "**good time**" means "having a good time".

You can instead use "**Good Day**" ([source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good%20day))